# WP_Query to get posts for two different taxonomies using 'OR'

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the posts for two different taxonomies.

I want to list posts only if those posts *either* have tag `longform` *or* the `post_format` is type `link`.

I have tried the below code, but it's not working:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'link' ) // Single terms as string - multiple as array
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'Tag',
        'field' => 'id',
       'tag__in' => array('16') // 16 is the code for tag longform
    )
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$terms = array('link');
$tax = array(16)

 $args = array( 
                           'post_type' => 'post',
                           'tax_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'OR',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                        'field'    => 'slug',
                                        'terms'    => $terms,
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'space',
                                        'field'    => 'id',
                                        'tag__in'    => $tax,
                                    ),
                            ),
                           'posts_per_page' => 2
                        );


                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This should work!

Comment: can you please edit your answer with the exact id and slug that i mentioned in the question, because i have some confusion with your answer.

Comment: @Hussain its not working, actually i made a shortcode in function.php file to list the posts, dont know where the error is, if i put single condition, like for `'tag' => 'longform'` then its working.